# String functions not working in stored procedure in SQL

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have written code for stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.Store_Reviews_GetByProduct
    @PortalID int,
    @ProductID int

    AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    SELECT r.ReviewID, r.PortalID, r.ProductID, r.UserName, r.Rating, LEFT(r.Comments,200), r.Authorized, r.CreatedDate, p.ModelName
    FROM dbo.Store_Reviews r
        LEFT JOIN dbo.Store_Products p
            ON r.ProductID = p.ProductID
    WHERE r.PortalID = @PortalID
    AND r.ProductID = @ProductID
    ORDER BY r.CreatedDate DESC
```

In that the `LEFT` function is not working, instead it gives no results or select none.

I have used `Substring` function as well like `SUBSTRING(r.comments, 0, 200)` but it also gives no result.

How can I get first 200 characters of comments column??

All answers are appreciated..

Comment: SQL isn't my strong suit, but you might need to alias the result of the string function for it show up reliably in your results.

Comment: Can't reproduce - works just fine on e.g. the `AdventureWorks` sample DB....

Comment: I don't think `LEFT()` is the issue. Does it return the entire content of comment if you remove it?

Comment: Table definition Please.

Comment: Does this also fail in Management Studio, or only in your client program?

Answer (score 1):

this works fine as well

```
SUBSTRING(r.comments,1 ,200)
```